# how to pattern match and change all occurrences of subexpression in expression?

Tags: python, sympy

Using sympy, I need to replace all occurrence  of `exp(C+anything)` with `C*exp(anything)`. Because `exp(C)` is constant, I just write at as `C`.

I can do this for one occurrence of `exp` in the expression. But do not how to do it if there are than one instance.

For example, for one instance, as in `x+exp(C_0+3*x)+3*y`, I need to change it to `x+C_0*exp(3*x)+3*y`

For one instance, this seems to work after some trial and error

```
from sympy import *
x,y,C_0 = symbols('x y C_0')
expr=x+exp(C_0+3*x)+3*y
#first check if exp is in the expression
if  any([isinstance(a, exp) for a in preorder_traversal(expr)]):
    p_1=Wild('p1');p_2=Wild('p_2');p_3=Wild('p_3')
    r=(p_1+exp(C_0+p_2)+p_3).matches(expr)
    expr.subs(exp(C_0+r[p_2]),C_0*exp(r[p_2]))
```

Which gives

```
C_0*exp(3*x) + x + 3*y
```

But what about something like `x+exp(C_0+3*x)+3*y+exp(C_0+30*x+y)` which I need to change to `x+C_0*exp(3*x)+3*y+C_0*exp(30*x+y)` I can't make special pattern match for each possible case. I need a way to change *all* occurrences

In Mathematica, I do the above as follows

```
expr = x + Exp[c + 3*x]*3*y + 3*y + Exp[c + 30*x + y]
expr /. Exp[c + any_] :> (c Exp[any])
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I actually prefer to tell Python just to change `exp(C+anything)` to `C*exp(anything)` without having to give pattern for the overall expression, since that can change in many way.

I am sure the above is also possible in python/sympy. Any hints how to do it?

Comment: Aside: SymPy expressions are immutable: the method `expr.subs` does not modify `expr`, so the value it returns needs to be assigned to something.

Comment: @Alex yes, I knew that, I was just printing the result for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for function `exp` inside of the expression, check whether its argument is `Add`, and then whether `C_0` is among the arguments of `Add`. Then build a thing to replace `exp` with. Consider the following:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, C_0 = symbols('x y C_0')
expr = x + exp(C_0+3*x) + 3*y + exp(y+C_0+30*x) - exp(x+y-C_0) + exp(x*y)

exp_sum = [(a, a.args[0].args) for a in preorder_traversal(expr) if a.func == exp and a.args[0].func == Add]
exp_sum = [p for p in exp_sum if C_0 in p[1]]

new_exp = [C_0*exp(Add(*[x for x in p[1] if x != C_0])) for p in exp_sum]

for (old, new) in zip(exp_sum, new_exp):
    expr = expr.subs(old[0], new)
```

Initially, `exp_sum` contains all parts of the form `exp(Add(...))`. After that it's filtered down to sums containing `C_0`. New exponentials are formed by taking all summands that are not `C_0`, adding them, applying `exp` and multiplying by `C_0`. Then substitution happens.

To clarify the process, here is what `exp_sum` is in the above example: a list of tuples (exponential and the summands inside):

```
 [(exp(C_0 + 3*x), (C_0, 3*x)), (exp(C_0 + 30*x + y), (C_0, y, 30*x))]
```

And this is `new_exp`

```
 [C_0*exp(3*x), C_0*exp(30*x + y)]
```

Finally, `expr` at the end:

```
 C_0*exp(3*x) + C_0*exp(30*x + y) + x + 3*y + exp(x*y) - exp(-C_0 + x + y)
```

Notice that exp(-C_0...) is not affected by the change; it's not a part of the pattern.